# Recommend a way to draw thousands of particles (liquid) per frame in Unity3d

Tags: unity, rendering, particles

I'm writing a plugin for [this](http://google.github.io/liquidfun/) library for Unity3d.
I have it working and now I am looking for an efficient way to draw the particles.
My 1st test just uses sprites and runs fine on my laptop but I doubt it will be so good on a mobile device.

Is there a cheap way of simply drawing lots of particles to the screen each frame?
The library generates an array of all the particle positions which updates in FixedUpdate() so I can just draw everything in that array each frame.

I'm thinking maybe somehting in the [Graphics](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Graphics.html) namespace would handy here, like maybe [Graphics.DrawTexture](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Graphics.DrawTexture.html)

Also I might consider doing some kind of metaballs like pass over the particles to make them look more liquid like.

Comment: Unity supports sprites rather well now. With hardware, if you are using pooling for sprites (memory management) I find it hard to imagine you"ll get poor performance. Wat does you benchmark show on a mobile device and what would you like it to be?

Comment: I actually dont have it working for Android yet! + my tablet has just mysteriously died, so I wont get to test it till Monday. I was just assuming it would be bad cus atm I'm drawing 772 little particle sprites with alpha. On my laptop when theres lots of collisions going on it runs at 30fps and then goes back to 60fps. I will update this question after Ive actually tried it on Android

Comment: Yeah, you may need to optimize. I am looking forward to your findings. Are you pooling sprites or creating new sprites on the go? Also, how much computation power goes on just the collisions?

Comment: Suprisingly litte, thats basically the deal with this library. its a superset of box2d in c++ with particles added, the testbed demo ran at about 40 fps on my android device with 1000's of particles (though you know the guys who wrote it also did some really efficient rendering implementation too, probably)

Comment: Oh hey I didnt answer your question about pooling. IN my current test I am just creating all the sprites at the beginning. Though I will be creating and destroying particles in the real game. When you say pooling do you mean.. create a lot of sprites when the scene loads and set their position offscreen somewhere, then when a particle is created set a pool sprites position to it and when its destroyed set it back to the pool?

Comment: Yeah, I mean don't attempt to create particles during the scene. Create as many as you guesstimate will be needed. I guess you probably did that alread since it"s a liquid test, the number of particles is pretty const

Comment: Ok, Android doesnt like that. Frame rate starts to drop from 40 fps with c.400 sprites down to 1 after about 1200 sprites on screen. The ones in the pool (offscreen) dont seem to affect it much tho

Comment: How do they draw it here? http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mhs4S9Vkl_s
Does not seem like many particles though.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, quads can be replaced by triangles to save computational power.

Since a quad is made of two triangles, you can simply make a bigger triangle that will encompass the whole particle texture (if any) and add it a transparency shader.

You'll get an instant decrease of geometry computation by 50% compared to an all-quad system, for exactly the same result.

Comment: Are you able to explain how it is a 50% computational decrease?

Comment: Because a quad is 2 triangles and a triangle is one triangle :)

Comment: Right it will not reduce the whole particle computation but the geometry computation at least

Comment: You should include that in your answer for geometry noobs like me ;)

Comment: 1 less vertex shader (which may matter), 1 less triangle setup (which really doesn't matter as much)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use point primitives. It should be the fastest possible solution, you use just position for rendering, but you can set the point size and even a shader/texture, so it may look almost like a mesh.

If you want to go even further you can render this on some off-screen texture to make some post-processing, like edge detection or better normal creation - this way you'll get almost countless possibilities to get the look you want.